# How to protect my injected elements CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I develop an HTML widget that gets injected (as plain HTML, not iframe) to several websites.

The problem is that in some sites the style of my elements gets affected by the site's CSS (text alignment, underline, text spacing...).

Is there any way to prevent the site's CSS to affect the style of injected elements?

Comment: Before your code place CSS reset.

Comment: I guess you *could* use `!important`

Comment: Not really. The only way you could would be to override the offending styles with your own. But it sounds like you don't know which styles would be applied ahead of time, so it would seem nearly impossible to identify which styles you need to take into account.

Comment: Here you have all CSS / CSS3 properties.http://blog.icms.sk/func/CSS3Reset.php See source.

Comment: Add those styles to your elements or make a reset sheet to your container

Comment: @Pankucins I would try to avoid that

Comment: you can also have a remote stylesheet cdn for your widget to be used with, or use inline css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want reset ALL CSS properties, you can do it. It is big file, probbably not best solution, but it works.

```
.yourContainer * {
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;                        -moz-align-content: stretch;                        align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;                          -moz-align-items: stretch;                          align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-align-self: stretch;                           -moz-align-self: stretch;                           align-self: stretch;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;                           -moz-animation-delay: 0s;                           animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;                   -moz-animation-direction: normal;                   animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0s;                        -moz-animation-duration: 0s;                        animation-duration: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;                     -moz-animation-fill-mode: none;                     animation-fill-mode: none;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;                  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;                  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-name: none;                          -moz-animation-name: none;                          animation-name: none;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;                 -moz-animation-play-state: running;                 animation-play-state: running;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;               -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;               animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;                           -moz-app-region: no-drag;                           app-region: no-drag;
  -webkit-appearance: none;                              -moz-appearance: none;                              appearance: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;                  -moz-backface-visibility: visible;                  backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;                   -moz-background-clip: border-box;                   background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-composite: source-over;             -moz-background-composite: source-over;             background-composite: source-over;
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;                -moz-background-origin: padding-box;                background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-size: auto;                         -moz-background-size: auto;                         background-size: auto;
  -webkit-border-fit: border;                            -moz-border-fit: border;                            border-fit: border;
  -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;                -moz-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;                border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
  -webkit-border-image: none;                            -moz-border-image: none;                            border-image: none;
  -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;                  -moz-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;                  border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;                            -moz-box-align: stretch;                            box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: slice;                   -moz-box-decoration-break: slice;                   box-decoration-break: slice;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;                         -moz-box-direction: normal;                         box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;                                   -moz-box-flex: 0;                                   box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex-group: 1;                             -moz-box-flex-group: 1;                             box-flex-group: 1;
  -webkit-box-lines: single;                             -moz-box-lines: single;                             box-lines: single;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;                          -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;                          box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;                        -moz-box-orient: horizontal;                        box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;                               -moz-box-pack: start;                               box-pack: start;
  -webkit-box-reflect: none;                             -moz-box-reflect: none;                             box-reflect: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;                              -moz-box-shadow: none;                              box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-clip-path: none;                               -moz-clip-path: none;                               clip-path: none;
  -webkit-color-correction: default;                     -moz-color-correction: default;                     color-correction: default;
  -webkit-column-axis: auto;                             -moz-column-axis: auto;                             column-axis: auto;
  -webkit-column-break-after: auto;                      -moz-column-break-after: auto;                      column-break-after: auto;
  -webkit-column-break-before: auto;                     -moz-column-break-before: auto;                     column-break-before: auto;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: auto;                     -moz-column-break-inside: auto;                     column-break-inside: auto;
  -webkit-column-count: auto;                            -moz-column-count: auto;                            column-count: auto;
  -webkit-column-gap: normal;                            -moz-column-gap: normal;                            column-gap: normal;
  -webkit-column-progression: normal;                    -moz-column-progression: normal;                    column-progression: normal;
  -webkit-column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);               -moz-column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);               column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-column-rule-style: none;                       -moz-column-rule-style: none;                       column-rule-style: none;
  -webkit-column-rule-width: 0px;                        -moz-column-rule-width: 0px;                        column-rule-width: 0px;
  -webkit-column-span: none;                             -moz-column-span: none;                             column-span: none;
  -webkit-column-width: auto;                            -moz-column-width: auto;                            column-width: auto;
  -webkit-filter: none;                                  -moz-filter: none;                                  filter: none;
  -webkit-flex-basis: auto;                              -moz-flex-basis: auto;                              flex-basis: auto;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;                           -moz-flex-direction: row;                           flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;                                  -moz-flex-grow: 0;                                  flex-grow: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;                                -moz-flex-shrink: 1;                                flex-shrink: 1;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;                             -moz-flex-wrap: nowrap;                             flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-flow-from: none;                               -moz-flow-from: none;                               flow-from: none;
  -webkit-flow-into: none;                               -moz-flow-into: none;                               flow-into: none;
  -webkit-font-kerning: auto;                            -moz-font-kerning: auto;                            font-kerning: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: auto;                          -moz-font-smoothing: auto;                          font-smoothing: auto;
  -webkit-font-variant-ligatures: normal;                -moz-font-variant-ligatures: normal;                font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  -webkit-grid-after: auto;                              -moz-grid-after: auto;                              grid-after: auto;
  -webkit-grid-auto-columns: auto;                       -moz-grid-auto-columns: auto;                       grid-auto-columns: auto;
  -webkit-grid-auto-flow: none;                          -moz-grid-auto-flow: none;                          grid-auto-flow: none;
  -webkit-grid-auto-rows: auto;                          -moz-grid-auto-rows: auto;                          grid-auto-rows: auto;
  -webkit-grid-before: auto;                             -moz-grid-before: auto;                             grid-before: auto;
  -webkit-grid-columns: none;                            -moz-grid-columns: none;                            grid-columns: none;
  -webkit-grid-end: auto;                                -moz-grid-end: auto;                                grid-end: auto;
  -webkit-grid-rows: none;                               -moz-grid-rows: none;                               grid-rows: none;
  -webkit-grid-start: auto;                              -moz-grid-start: auto;                              grid-start: auto;
  -webkit-highlight: none;                               -moz-highlight: none;                               highlight: none;
  -webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;                     -moz-hyphenate-character: auto;                     hyphenate-character: auto;
  -webkit-hyphenate-limit-after: auto;                   -moz-hyphenate-limit-after: auto;                   hyphenate-limit-after: auto;
  -webkit-hyphenate-limit-before: auto;                  -moz-hyphenate-limit-before: auto;                  hyphenate-limit-before: auto;
  -webkit-hyphenate-limit-lines: no-limit;               -moz-hyphenate-limit-lines: no-limit;               hyphenate-limit-lines: no-limit;
  -webkit-hyphens: manual;                               -moz-hyphens: manual;                               hyphens: manual;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;                   -moz-justify-content: flex-start;                   justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-line-align: none;                              -moz-line-align: none;                              line-align: none;
  -webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;       -moz-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;       line-box-contain: block inline replaced;
  -webkit-line-break: auto;                              -moz-line-break: auto;                              line-break: auto;
  -webkit-line-clamp: none;                              -moz-line-clamp: none;                              line-clamp: none;
  -webkit-line-grid: none;                               -moz-line-grid: none;                               line-grid: none;
  -webkit-line-snap: none;                               -moz-line-snap: none;                               line-snap: none;
  -webkit-locale: auto;                                  -moz-locale: auto;                                  locale: auto;
  -webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;               -moz-margin-after-collapse: collapse;               margin-after-collapse: collapse;
  -webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse;              -moz-margin-before-collapse: collapse;              margin-before-collapse: collapse;
  -webkit-marquee-direction: auto;                       -moz-marquee-direction: auto;                       marquee-direction: auto;
  -webkit-marquee-increment: 6px;                        -moz-marquee-increment: 6px;                        marquee-increment: 6px;
  -webkit-marquee-repetition: infinite;                  -moz-marquee-repetition: infinite;                  marquee-repetition: infinite;
  -webkit-marquee-style: scroll;                         -moz-marquee-style: scroll;                         marquee-style: scroll;
  -webkit-mask-box-image: none;                          -moz-mask-box-image: none;                          mask-box-image: none;
  -webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0px;                    -moz-mask-box-image-outset: 0px;                    mask-box-image-outset: 0px;
  -webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;                -moz-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;                mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;
  -webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;                  -moz-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;                  mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;
  -webkit-mask-box-image-source: none;                   -moz-mask-box-image-source: none;                   mask-box-image-source: none;
  -webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto;                    -moz-mask-box-image-width: auto;                    mask-box-image-width: auto;
  -webkit-mask-clip: border-box;                         -moz-mask-clip: border-box;                         mask-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-mask-composite: source-over;                   -moz-mask-composite: source-over;                   mask-composite: source-over;
  -webkit-mask-image: none;                              -moz-mask-image: none;                              mask-image: none;
  -webkit-mask-origin: border-box;                       -moz-mask-origin: border-box;                       mask-origin: border-box;
  -webkit-mask-position: 0% 0%;                          -moz-mask-position: 0% 0%;                          mask-position: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;                           -moz-mask-repeat: repeat;                           mask-repeat: repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: auto;                               -moz-mask-size: auto;                               mask-size: auto;
  -webkit-nbsp-mode: normal;                             -moz-nbsp-mode: normal;                             nbsp-mode: normal;
  -webkit-order: 0;                                      -moz-order: 0;                                      order: 0;
  -webkit-perspective: none;                             -moz-perspective: none;                             perspective: none;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 640px 345px;               -moz-perspective-origin: 640px 345px;               perspective-origin: 640px 345px;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: economy;                   -moz-print-color-adjust: economy;                   print-color-adjust: economy;
  -webkit-region-break-after: auto;                      -moz-region-break-after: auto;                      region-break-after: auto;
  -webkit-region-break-before: auto;                     -moz-region-break-before: auto;                     region-break-before: auto;
  -webkit-region-break-inside: auto;                     -moz-region-break-inside: auto;                     region-break-inside: auto;
  -webkit-region-overflow: auto;                         -moz-region-overflow: auto;                         region-overflow: auto;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;                         -moz-rtl-ordering: logical;                         rtl-ordering: logical;
  -webkit-shape-inside: outside-shape;                   -moz-shape-inside: outside-shape;                   shape-inside: outside-shape;
  -webkit-shape-margin: 0px;                             -moz-shape-margin: 0px;                             shape-margin: 0px;
  -webkit-shape-outside: auto;                           -moz-shape-outside: auto;                           shape-outside: auto;
  -webkit-shape-padding: 0px;                            -moz-shape-padding: 0px;                            shape-padding: 0px;
  -webkit-svg-shadow: none;                              -moz-svg-shadow: none;                              svg-shadow: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.180392);  -moz-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.180392);  tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.180392);
  -webkit-text-combine: none;                            -moz-text-combine: none;                            text-combine: none;
  -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none;              -moz-text-decorations-in-effect: none;              text-decorations-in-effect: none;
  -webkit-text-emphasis-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);             -moz-text-emphasis-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);             text-emphasis-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-text-emphasis-position: over;                  -moz-text-emphasis-position: over;                  text-emphasis-position: over;
  -webkit-text-emphasis-style: none;                     -moz-text-emphasis-style: none;                     text-emphasis-style: none;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);                 -moz-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);                 text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-text-orientation: vertical-right;              -moz-text-orientation: vertical-right;              text-orientation: vertical-right;
  -webkit-text-security: none;                           -moz-text-security: none;                           text-security: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);               -moz-text-stroke-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);               text-stroke-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;                        -moz-text-stroke-width: 0px;                        text-stroke-width: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: none;                               -moz-transform: none;                               transform: none;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 640px 345px;                 -moz-transform-origin: 640px 345px;                 transform-origin: 640px 345px;
  -webkit-transform-style: flat;                         -moz-transform-style: flat;                         transform-style: flat;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;                          -moz-transition-delay: 0s;                          transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;                       -moz-transition-duration: 0s;                       transition-duration: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;                      -moz-transition-property: all;                      transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;              -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;              transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-user-drag: auto;                               -moz-user-drag: auto;                               user-drag: auto;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-only;                        -moz-user-modify: read-only;                        user-modify: read-only;
  -webkit-user-select: text;                             -moz-user-select: text;                             user-select: text;
  -webkit-wrap-flow: auto;                               -moz-wrap-flow: auto;                               wrap-flow: auto;
  -webkit-wrap-through: wrap;                            -moz-wrap-through: wrap;                            wrap-through: wrap;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;                   -moz-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;                   writing-mode: horizontal-tb;

    alignment-baseline: auto;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: none;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  baseline-shift: baseline;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-image-outset: 0px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  border-image-slice: 100%;
  border-image-source: none;
  border-image-width: 1;
  border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  caption-side: top;
  clear: none;
  clip: auto;
  clip-path: none;
  clip-rule: nonzero;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color-interpolation: srgb;
  color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb;
  color-rendering: auto;
  cursor: auto;
  direction: ltr;
  display: block;
  dominant-baseline: auto;
  empty-cells: show;
  fill: #000000;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  filter: none;
  float: none;
  flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  flood-opacity: 1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg;
  glyph-orientation-vertical: auto;
  height: auto;
  image-rendering: auto;
  kerning: 0;
  left: auto;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: normal;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: disc;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  marker-end: none;
  marker-mid: none;
  marker-start: none;
  mask: none;
  mask-type: luminance;
  max-height: none;
  max-width: none;
  min-height: 0px;
  min-width: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  orphans: auto;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  outline-offset: 0px;
  outline-style: none;
  outline-width: 0px;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-before: auto;
  page-break-inside: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: static;
  resize: none;
  right: auto;
  shape-rendering: auto;
  speak: normal;
  stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stop-opacity: 1;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 1;
  tab-size: 8;
  table-layout: auto;
  text-align: start;
  text-anchor: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-overflow: clip;
  text-rendering: auto;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-transform: none;
  top: auto;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0s;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  unicode-bidi: normal;
  vector-effect: none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  visibility: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  widows: auto;
  width: auto;
  word-break: normal;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  word-wrap: normal;
  writing-mode: lr-tb;
  z-index: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. Paste the code there in the top of your widget's stylesheet, it will reset almost all CSS properties that can affect your display. If you don`t want to visit the link, here it is:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: none;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not reset all properties. What about `Background-color` etc. ?

Comment: Well, I said _almost_ all, and if you want to reset these properties, just add them to the big rule. In the link I posted, the author explains this isn`t a full reset and should probably be modified for your needs, or in his words: "this is a starting point, not a self-contained black box of no-touchiness."

Answer (score 1):

Typically no, there isn't. Ultimately, if you're putting HTML code into someone else's site, you're implicitly giving them control over how that HTML is styled.

Even using `!important` can be overridden with another `!important` style, or worst case by a bit of Javascript to set the style directly on the element. (And in any case, `!important` is considered bad practice, so you probably don't want to do that, right)

You could, of course, use Javascript yourself to set the style, but that's still vulnerable to the site owner doing the same thing after you've done it.

The only really viable solution is to put your entire widget into an iframe. This is what Google do for their ads, etc. This will do a good job of isolating your widget code from the main site, and will prevent any possibility of the site owner inadvertently overwriting your styles. There may be still be ways for them to force the issue, but it gets a lot harder when you're dealing with a cross-site iframe, as the built-in browser security restrictions come into play.

But the real question is: do you really *need* to do this? How important is it for your styles to be maintained as you've defined them? Maybe your widget looks better on a particular site if it's rendered using that site's default font? Maybe the site owner has a corporate requirement for specific fonts or colours? (some companies can be annoyingly picky about this). Surely if it's on their site, they should have at least some degree of control over it? If it looks rubbish when they're done with it, then it's their fault.

Now I know the above paragraph won't apply to everyone. Maybe you're asking this because you don't want users hiding your copyright text, or something like that. But in some cases, you do need to ask yourself the question of whether you're imposing restrictions for the sake of it; whether they're actually worth the effort, or whether they might just annoy users who want to do something perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

In the nature of the CSS is inheritance. I.e. if you don't send a property to an element it will get it from its parent. As far as I understood you are adding an widget as code. I mean your code is injected inside another page and there is no iframe involved. So, your styling should be an inline styling like:

```
<div class="widget" style="padding: 0;">
...
</div>
```

The first solution which you may try is to put reset styles in your very top container. So all its children inherit the missing properties from there. However this is not so good, because there are tons of properties and adding them inside the tag directly looks weird.

Using !important is good enough, but that's only in those cases where you know which style will be chnaged.

I think that if you don't use iframe it will be difficult to have absolutely custom looking widget. You may try few crazy things like

- use custom tags and style them separately
- use more images instead of CSS. The images will look stay untouched

Answer (score -2):

create an id for an encapsulating injected div & then style as you wish.  That will always keep things intact.  Otherwise, you can't prevent things from happening, only protect.

Comment: this would only prevent some rules that use hierarchical selectors from applying.

Comment: yeah, it's called css, cascading?

Comment: google OOCSS and please stop using this above bullcrap anymore

Answer (score -4):

In your css be as specific as posible. So lets say you have the following HTML

```
<div id="myWidget">
    <div class="someContent">test</div>
</div>
```

and you want tell that someContent needs to be red, use the following css:

```
#myWidget div.someContent{#ff0000;}
```