# Unique stylesheet for embedded content

Tags: html, css

I have some html markup & css styling that will be embedded on several thousands of different websites. I want this section to only use my own stylesheet, while ignoring the original site's css.

Apart from using unique prefixes for all classes and id's, is there a way to not apply site wide css rules on a certain area, and only use my own styling?

Comment: Can't you make use of the `cascading` part of the style sheet? `css` uses rules to determine which styles should be applied. Adding an extra css file to your page should be sufficient.

Comment: is it possible to link your own css file rather than current css file?

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear, my code is embedded in someone else's site. I don't want his rules to apply on my markup. I will rephrase the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI `!important` declarations in user CSS will always win against CSS Author and User Agent ones (resource: [the cascade on Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/cascade/)), but that's not what you're *competing* with.

There's no way to *only* apply your CSS while *completely* ignoring the rest of the page, afaik (the C in CSS is there for a reason ;) ). But nevertheless, here's a bunch of things that should help:

- `!important` is very powerful. Only other declarations with this modifier have a chance to still be applied
- same for inline styles (not sure if it's as needed as it is for those dreaded HTML emails though)
- `id` have a strong specificity. A selector with 412 classes and no id has less specificity than one with 1 id and no class (that's why it's a bad practice according to OOCSS and css linters based on it. Ymmv)
- a nice trick allowing to artificially add to CSS specificity is `.c.c { prop:val}`: twice the specificity of `.c {}` and exactly the same scope. Imagine this with `id` ;) (you can also have an id on each and every ancestor of an element but you can't have 2 id on the same element)
- [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) and [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/unset)'d have been nice if it was supported by IE... Would be even better: [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/all) property but it's IE11+ and not in Safari
- So you'll have to read carefully MDN for each property you want to reset and apply its default value. Or read this *amazing* answer here on SO on a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464285/137626

Don't forget about declarations inside Media Queries that could apply on client websites: you (or you clients) won't see them until they resize their browser.
I care a lot about not having not too much specificity in general rules and then specific ones in default resolution, but in that last MQ (320 or 1600+) of a given project, I don't really care anymore if it' more convenient for me (i.e. faster) as I know for sure that I won't need to override it later. Ever.

EDIT: don't forget to take into account pseudos `:before` and `:after`. Normalize.css is now declaring `*, *:before, *:after { (-prefix-)box-sizing: border-box }` and that may be surprising if you also use them. Better not use them imho as they can't be styled in style attribute (same problem with MQ).
To annihilate any style these pseudos could have, this code:

```
high-specificity-selector *:before,
high-specificity-selector *:after {
  content: none !important
}
```

should be enough: no content, no pseudo.
/EDIT

If you're pretty serious about your project (*thousands of websites*, wow), you could also automatically test for the CSS applying on client's website in the wild, with tests verifying:

- the CSS values of a bunch of properties on a bunch of elements of your widget. Resource: http://csste.st/tools/
- the rendering of your widget compared to an initial screenshot with *teh* mighty [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS) (based on CasperJS, itself based on PhantomJS. Casper tests in WebKit but there are clones testing in Gecko/SlimerJS or with IE/TrifleJS)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. The csste.st link is a real eye opener.